# Is there any list of doping that could be found in daily food?

Tags: doping

As WADA states in [DIETARY AND NUTRITIONAL SUPPLEMENTS](https://www.wada-ama.org/en/questions-answers/dietary-and-nutritional-supplements):

> 1. CAN AN ATHLETE TEST POSITIVE FROM USING DIETARY/NUTRITIONAL SUPPLEMENTS? UP
>
> Extreme caution is recommended regarding supplement use.
>
> The use of dietary supplements by athletes is a concern because in
>   many countries the manufacturing and labeling of supplements may not
>   follow strict rules, which may lead to a supplement containing an
>   undeclared substance that is prohibited under anti-doping regulations.
>   A significant number of positive tests have been attributed to the
>   misuse of supplements and taking a poorly labeled dietary supplement
>   is not an adequate defense in a doping hearing.

And in [PROHIBITED LIST](https://www.wada-ama.org/en/questions-answers/prohibited-list):

> 11. CAN I TEST POSITIVE FOR INGESTING GLYCEROL FOUND IN FOODSTUFFS AND TOILETRIES OR FOR USING IT AS A LUBRICANT? UP
>
> Glycerol is prohibited as a plasma expander. The consumption of
>   quantities of glycerol far beyond those commonly found in e.g. foods,
>   beverages, personal care products, medicinal tablets tuffs, cough
>   syrup is required to produce an Adverse Analytical Finding. Therefore,
>   its prohibition is not intended to prevent the ingestion of this
>   substance in the amounts commonly found in foodstuffs and toiletries,
>   as such small quantities will not cause an athlete to test positive
>   for this Prohibited Substance.
>
> In addition, athletes with disabilities may use glycerol as a
>   lubricant agent for a catheter but this will not cause a problem in a
>   doping control for the aforementioned reasons.

Is there any cases like positive doping test because athlete ate some meat that was grown with hormones or steroids?

I am not asking about medicine. I am asking about daily food, is there anything that should be avoided?

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely.

I boxed in the late 90s while in college.  My dining hall was not feeding me enough so I was heavily smuggling food out for late night snacks.  I found out that the easiest food to smuggle out and that would actually take decent were the bagels.  And the only ones they had left at the end of the meals were the poppy seed ones.  So I was eating 4-5 very large poppy seed bagels a day for snacks.

Right before golden gloves finals we were taken to a facility, met agents, talked with some of us about joining Olympic team (not me), allowed our trainers to train us there... lots of fun actually.  But we also had weigh-ins and a drug test the first day.  And since I was a light middle weight weighing 190 I was having at least 5 of the poppy seed bagels a day to gain weight.

I was a completely drug free person (save beer).  Failed my first test - told me traces of morphine in my system.  It took two days to figure out why and many meetings with officials.  I also had doctors raising an eye brow when I explained to them I was eating 25-30 poppy seed bagels a week.  It was like a bad sitcom episode.  The only thing that kept me from getting kicked out is they actually called the school, spoke to the lady who ran the dining hall, and she knew I was taking the bagels every night - I listened to her on speaker.  (I think her exact words were that skinny guy who eats like a horse takes all the bagels every night.  We would throw them out anyway so I never cared.)

Answer (score 1):

According to the article ["Non-Intentional Doping in Sports"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/8259848_Non-Intentional_Doping_in_Sports) (by Mauricio Yonamine, Paula Rodrigues Garcia, Regina Lúcia Moreau) which refers to several real cases of positive doping tests and several researces, it is really possible to recieve banned substances into your body unintentionally (e.g. non-smokers could passively inhale enough marijuana, or eat as much poppy-seed-containing food so that it could result in positive test, as in @Coach-D case)

But the article is of 2004 year and limits (concentration of banned substance in urine) could have changed from that time.

Anyway it is possible to intentionally avoid consumption of such stuff.

P.S.: this is still **not full answer** to my question becouse **there is no up to date list of daily products that could possibly contain banned substances** (and better with evaluation of concentration wich is enough to be detected)